# how to get input from multiple users

Tags: python

This is a game for 3 players. In this game, a secret number between 1 and 99 is generated randomly. Each of the players take turns to guess this secret number. The player will be advised whether his guess is higher or lower than the randomly generated number. The game will end when one of the players makes the right guess.
The out would show the number of guesses each player made and the winner.

i already typed out some of the code:

```
import random

userNumber = input("enter a number between 1 and 99:")
secretNummber = random.randint(1,99)
if userNumber > secretNumber:
    print "too high..."
elif userNumber < secretNumber:
    print "too low..."
else:
    print "you made the right guess..."
print "secret number"+str(secretNumber)
```

Comment: Each guess a new number will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use a loop for each "round" of guessing, and then take 3 inputs per round:

```
import random

secretNumber = random.randint(1,99)

while True:
    for player in range(1,4):
        userNumber = input("Player %s: enter a number between 1 and 99:" % player)

        if userNumber > secretNumber:
            print "too high..."
        elif userNumber < secretNumber:
            print "too low..."
        else:
            print "Player %s, you made the right guess..." % player
            exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
from itertools import cycle

secretNumber = random.randint(1,99)

for player in cycle(["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"]):
    userNumber = int(raw_input("{}: enter a number between 1 and 99:".format(player)))

    if userNumber > secretNumber:
        print "too high..."
    elif userNumber < secretNumber:
        print "too low..."
    else:
        print "{}, you made the right guess...".format(player)
        break
```

Comment: is there a way to count the number of guesses

Comment: You could use `for guess_number, player in enumerate(cycle(["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"]), 1):`